# how to make a fixed position div relative to another div?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="myContainer">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" >
    <li class="active"><a href="#chat" data-toggle="tab">Chat</a></li>
    <li><a href="#users" data-toggle="tab">Users</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content" style="height:500px">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="chat">
      <div style="" >
        <? include("lorem.php");?>
        <div id="banner" style="position:fixed;top:560px;height:30px;width:100%;background-color:#F00"> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="users"> dd... </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

That works fine: problem is that

```
    <div id="banner" style="position:fixed;**top:560px**;height:30px;width:100%;background-color:#F00"> </div>
```

is absolute positionned at top:560px.

If `<div class="tab-content" style="height:500px">`has another height, I need to absolute position the banner !

Th goal is to create that template:

1) bootstrap tabs

2) a div inside one tab which is a div that will contain a chat

3) at bottom of that div, stuck a banner div which will contain the chat input text

regards

Here comes the desired result[image]

Answer (score 2):

Set 'banner' inside 'tab-container'. Set the position of banner to absolute and position it with bottom

```
<div id ="tab-container" ...>
 <div id="banner" style="position:absolute; bottom: -2px;">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not good ! Banner just diseappered !
I added the desired layout indeed as JPEG

Comment: if any parent element is hidden then show it or try " display:block !important; " on banner class

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, but it seems like this is what you want.

```
<div class="tab-content" style="position:relative">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="chat">
      <div style="" >
        <? include("lorem.php");?>
        <div id="banner" style="position:absolute;bottom:-30px;height:30px;width:100%;background-color:#F00"> </div>
```

This will make div#banner sit directly below div.tab-content, no matter how tall div.tab-content is.

http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Comment: not good: the banner now belongs to #chat.
So if chat scrolls, banner scraolls as well.
I want the banner to be at FIXED position JUST after the chat

Comment: Switch the position:relative to the div you want the banner to be attached to.

Answer (score 0):

Change `top:560px` to `bottom: 0`.

Remember that positioned elements (fixed, absolute, relative) are always relative to the closest parent element with another non-default position. Then check carefully the positions of your elements, that you didn't post.

Consider creating a [Fiddle](http://jsFiddle.net) too. JPEG sucks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm agreeing with Arinta, if the banner has disappeared you may need to check for typos in the css.  Some browsers come with a console, but most come with a 'right-click -> inspect' feature to check what css is being picked up.

Also if the text is hidden by the newly positioned div, you'll want the text to be visible.  Allow this by setting the padding-bottom to equal the chat's height.

Also the parent div (the one you have style='') needs a positioned tag for the absolute feature to work.  Fixed will work, but the banner becomes positioned relative to the entire page rather than the next-positioned element. (Up to you, but I recommend absolute).

```
<div style="padding-bottom: 30px; position: relative" >
  <? include("lorem.php");?>
  <div id="banner" style="position:absolute;bottom:-30px;height:30px;width:100%;background-color:#F00">
  </div>
```